# How to replace character stringers with numeric indices

Tags: r, string

How would you replace character strings with numeric values?

For example, suppose I have a vector like so,

```
n <- c(rep("Sam", 3), "Harry", rep("Sparky", 2), rep("Ted", 4), "Red")

>n
 [1] "Sam"    "Sam"    "Sam"    "Harry"  "Sparky" "Sparky" "Ted"    "Ted"    "Ted"   
[10] "Ted"    "Red"
```

I would like to get an output like this,

```
 [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

Where

- `Sam` is indexed by `1`
- `Harry` is indexed by `2`
- `Sparky` by `3`
- `Ted` by `4`
- `Red` by `5`.

Comment: If you don't care about the order of the indexed values, `as.integer(factor(n))`

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution using `factor` approach preserving desired order:

```
n <- factor(n, levels = unique(n))
> as.numeric(n)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

Comment: That's the best possible answer to this problem and R idiomatic.

Comment: and this is the best comment that I ever received, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
match(n, unique(n))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also do:

```
as.numeric(sapply(n,function(x) grep(x,unique(n))))
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

or

```
sapply(n,function(x) grep(x,unique(n)))
 Sam    Sam    Sam  Harry Sparky Sparky    Ted    Ted    Ted    Ted    Red 
     1      1      1      2      3      3      4      4      4      4      5
```

if you would like to see the corresponding name

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants a more general approach:

```
id_matrix <- paste0(unique(n),"'s randomID")
names(id_matrix) <- unique(n)
```

gives:

```
# Sam               Harry              Sparky                 Ted                 Red 
#"Sam's randomID"  "Harry's randomID" "Sparky's randomID"    "Ted's randomID"    "Red's randomID"
```

Then replace:

```
unname(id_matrix[n])
```

gives:

```
#[1] "Sam's randomID"    "Sam's randomID"    "Sam's randomID"    "Harry's randomID"  "Sparky's randomID" "Sparky's randomID" "Ted's randomID"   
#[8] "Ted's randomID"    "Ted's randomID"    "Ted's randomID"    "Red's randomID"    "Sam's randomID"
```

data:

```
n <- c(rep("Sam", 3), "Harry", rep("Sparky", 2), rep("Ted", 4), "Red","Sam")
```